# Transpose a table with one row and many columns using SAS SQL

Tags: sas, transpose, proc-sql

My table has only 1 row and many columns. I need to return only 1 column and many rows. It is possible to do a transpose via SAS SQL?

Before:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
   1       2       3       4
```

After:

```
column
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

Comment: Not a simple solution. SQL doesn't allow variable list short cuts. You should use proc transpose. If you insist on SQL then you'll need a macro to first determine the number of columns and then generate your union statements dynamically. I don't think it's worth the effort personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use PROC TRANSPOSE you don't have to know how many columns or even the names PROC TRANSPOSE will transpose all numeric columns by default.

```
proc transpose data= out= ;
   run;
```

Comment: SAS will convert all to character.  You can just use VAR _ALL_;

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention SAS SQL (as opposed to any other SAS proc), this is a solution, though it will be a bit verbose if you have a lot of columns:

```
PROC SQL;

    SELECT column1 AS column FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column2 AS column FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column3 AS column FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column4 AS column FROM table;

    /* Add for each column */

QUIT;
```

This simply unions (stacks) each column.

Comment: but i dont know, how many columns contains table... i cant use this, exist some another solution?

Comment: Why don't you know how many columns there are in your table??

Comment: because this script must be universal for more tables and each table contains a different number of columns